# Who is this woman wielding Mjölnir?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, character-identification, mjolnir, thor-love-and-thunder

The new *Thor: Love and Thunder* trailer dropped. After the title hero they teased a woman catching Mjölnir, Captain America-style ([See trailer at around the 1:19 mark](https://youtu.be/tgB1wUcmbbw?t=79)).

[image: Blonde woman holding Mjölnir and wearing Thor's distinctive outfit including winged helmet and red cape.]

Who is this character?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's the [MCU version of Jane Foster](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Jane_Foster), as portrayed by Natalie Portman.

> The first teaser for Marvel Studios’ Thor: Love and Thunder has arrived, offering long-awaited clues to what’s in store for the God of Thunder. The film finds Thor (Chris Hemsworth) on a journey unlike anything he’s ever faced — a quest for inner peace. But his retirement is interrupted by a galactic killer known as Gorr the God Butcher (Christian Bale), who seeks the extinction of the gods. **To combat the threat, Thor enlists the help of King Valkyrie (Tessa Thompson), Korg (Taika Waititi), and ex-girlfriend Jane Foster (Natalie Portman), who — to Thor’s surprise — inexplicably wields his magical hammer, Mjolnir, as the Mighty Thor.**
>
> <sub>[‘Thor: Love and Thunder’: First Teaser Reveals a Cosmic Adventure](https://www.marvel.com/articles/movies/thor-love-and-thunder-first-teaser)</sub>

Portman previously posed for the press, holding a prop of Thor's hammer, at Comic Con 2019.

[image]

> **The upcoming *Thor: Love and Thunder* will do the thing that no Marvel fan ever thought would happen, bring back Oscar winner Natalie Portman as Jane Foster.** Not only will the star be back as her character for the first time since 2013's *Thor: The Dark World*, but **her character will become the God of Thunder and pick up the hammer as The Mighty Thor.**
>
> <sub>[Comic Con 2019: Natalie Portman to play female version of Thor](https://comicbook.com/marvel/news/thor-love-and-thunder-star-natalie-portman-bulking-up-marvel-return/)</sub>

This aspect of the film's plot is inspired by a storyline from the comics, where the [Earth-616 version of Jane](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Jane_Foster_(Earth-616)) wielded Mjolnir and became 'Thor' for a while.

> **And then there's that gender-swapping twist expected in "Thor: Love and Thunder": if it follows the much-admired comic book storyline from writer Jason Aaron, Thor's paramour Jane Foster (played by Portman), through a poignant twist of fate, will assume the mantle of thunder goddess when she proves worthy of wielding Thor's hammer.**
>
> **"We love the story -- it's one of the best comic runs recently," said Feige. "[Director Taika Waitit] would flip through and read that run while he was doing 'Ragnarok.'** And I think when he agreed to come back and do another Thor, he was like, 'How do we--?' This is a very big movie that'll be folding in a lot of elements. That is a huge important part of it. He pitched it to us, and we were totally in. We loved it. We'd been in touch with Natalie. She's part of the MCU family and we put she and Taika together. It took one meeting and she agreed to do it."
>
> <sub>[Kevin Feige reveals the thinking behind Marvel's Phase Four](https://edition.cnn.com/2019/07/21/entertainment/kevin-feige-comic-con/index.html)</sub>

The comicbook storyline was mostly told throughout *[Thor Vol. 4](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thor_Vol_4)* (2014–2015) and *[Mighty Thor Vol. 3](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Mighty_Thor_Vol_3)* (2016–2017), although the Jane Foster Thor also appeared in other books, such as *[All-New, All-Different Avengers Vol. 1](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/All-New,_All-Different_Avengers_Vol_1)* (2016).